# C# How can I change content of the clipboard based on current clipboard content?

Tags: c#, clipboard

I'm curious as to add a feature to my program so when it detects the clipboard text to be a certain length and start with certain characters, when they paste the text from the clipboard it pastes someting different.

Example:

User copies 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

--Program intercepts recognizes the certain string length and starting characters and switches text--

User pastes 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please show what have you achieved so far? SO cannot write code for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question does not show any research effort, so please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sounds like bad UX to me.   Would it not be better that they first paste it into one of your textboxes and then click a button called say **Reverse** which performs the actual reversal?

Comment: There is a big danger here where the modification of the clipboard data, WITHIN the WM_PASTE event, results in an endless loop of responding to your own event.  If you're lucky, you may even discover the beloved namesake of this site.  (StackOverflow)

Answer (score 2):

**If you just need directions:**

*To copy to clipboard you can use:*

```
Clipboard.SetText("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

*Use this to get text from ClipBoard:*

```
string s = Clipboard.GetText();
```

After getting the text you can apply your rules like checking length and Starting characters and do your conversion and finally add the converted text to your textbox.

```
if (s.Length > 16 && s.StartsWith("abc")
{
   // do your stuff here 
   string convertedText = ConvertText(s);
   //finally
   txtBoxToPasteTo.Text = convertedText;
}
```

To intercept a paste, you need to create a custom textbox

```
class InterceptedTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
    // WM_PASTE:
    if (m.Msg == 0x302 && Clipboard.ContainsText()) {
        this.Text = ConvertText(Clipboard.GetText());
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
}
```

[References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz40084e(v=vs.110).aspx)